# the following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in active designer

Tags: c#

I am working on design of a window application in c# using .net framework. I need line, rectangle and ellipse controls for this. For this added

```
Micosoft.VisualBasic and 
Micosoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks dll
```

Now when i try to add line, rectangle and ellipse controls by Creating New Tab in toolbox and then went to choose items from wpf components and when i select line, rectangle and ellipse controls and click ok it shows error as

```
the following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in active designer
```

Kindly help me here. I tried a lot but unable to solve this.

Comment: Please elaborate what 'design of a window application' means. Another question, why do you use VisualBasic with C# and .Net framework? Is this a design choice? ~Edit: I did not downvote, have you considered you are not using the correct namespaces for WPF?

Comment: It means Windows forms Application using c# in Visual studio 2019

Comment: Am I correct in asuming you're running on version 4.x .net? WPF and Winforms are not the same in that version.

Comment: I am Working on development of Windows form application using c# on Visual studio 2019 having version 4.7.2. Also it not wpf application.

Comment: Perhaps [this][1] can be of use


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-creating-new-wpf-content-on-windows-forms-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8